# TryGetFeatureValue always 0 for Unity XR Input's CommonUsages.trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am developing a VR game in Unity (2020.3.15f2) using the XR Interaction Toolkit package (1.0.0-pre.5) for my Oculus Quest 2. At this stage in my development, I am trying to recognize presses to the trigger and grip buttons on the controllers respectively in order to animate some 3D hand models. Here's the script I've written to accomplish this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class HandPresence : MonoBehaviour {
    public InputDeviceCharacteristics controllerCharacteristics;
    public GameObject handModelPrefab;
    private InputDevice targetDevice;
    private GameObject spawnedHandModel;
    private Animator handAnimator;

    void Start() {
      TryInitialize();
    }

    void TryInitialize() {
      List<InputDevice> devices = new List<InputDevice>();
      InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(controllerCharacteristics, devices);

      if (devices.Count > 0) {
        targetDevice = devices[0];
        spawnedHandModel = Instantiate(handModelPrefab, transform);
        handAnimator = spawnedHandModel.GetComponent<Animator>();
      }
    }

    void UpdateHandAnimation() {
      if (targetDevice.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.trigger, out float triggerValue)) {
        handAnimator.SetFloat("Trigger", triggerValue);
      } else {
        handAnimator.SetFloat("Trigger", 0);
      }
      if (targetDevice.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.grip, out float gripValue)) {
        handAnimator.SetFloat("Grip", gripValue);
      } else {
        handAnimator.SetFloat("Grip", 0);
      }
    }

    void Update()
    {
      if (!targetDevice.isValid) {
        TryInitialize();
      } else {
        spawnedHandModel.SetActive(true);
        UpdateHandAnimation();
      }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the values of both `triggerValue` and `gripValue` are always 0. The value of `targetDevice` looks fine. I also tried using `triggerButton`, `gripButton`, `primaryButton`, etc. and they are always 0/false as well. The hand models show up just fine and their movement is in sync with the movement of the controllers, but they just don't seem to want to register any button presses.

I've been stuck on this one for hours and would very much appreciate any insight, thank you!

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @MarekStój I have not. I am considering starting a bounty.

Comment: Did you set the Controllercharacteristics in the editor? I can't see you setting them in code. Also, have you tried contacting Valem about it?

Answer (score 1):

Is your project setup with the (new) Input System? I have no problem detecting there trigger and grip values.

Also make sure the targetDevice actually uses trigger and grip features, maybe it is another device such as the HMD.

Answer (score 0):

I would say because you are expecting a true/false or on/off digital response from your input.  You expect the trigger to either be on (1) or off(0), whereas the trigger can also be an analog value returned, as well as other input values.  (i.e. "bool" variable types will not work and/or will return errors.)

Get it?